# How do I add wireless encryption method to my columns?

Tags: wireshark

I know how to create custom columns however I am having a hard time generating the filter I need in order to determine if a network packet is Open/WEP/WPA protected. Wireshark has this capability, I have seen it in the WLAN Statistics tool.

I would assume it would be some sort of wlan_mgt.rsn. However I have only got wlan.rsn.akms.type to display 'PSK'. I am close to what I want just not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try wlan_mgt.rsn.akms.type.
See also the Wireshark [Display Filter Reference: wlan_mgt](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/w/wlan_mgt.html)